# Windows 8 RT : Run application at startup

Tags: .net, windows-8

I am creating a Windows 8 RT app and would like to run the app itself as soon the Windows 8 gets started..

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
You can't.  It is up to the user which apps to launch and when to launch them.  This is fundamental to the Windows 8 app philosophy.

**Longer answer**
You could probably achieve your goals in a better way than this.  If you can update your answer with an overview of what you want to achieve, we may be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: I am creating a simple survey app which will running on kiosks having surface RT. I want that app to automatically get started is Surface gets restarted

Comment: Windows RT is unsuitable for a kiosk environment, I'm afraid.  You would need to look into Embedded for this purpose.

Comment: Indeed, rt doesn't let you run win32 code. You could probably do it using a deep link or similar, but I can't believe that will give you quite the experience you are looking for